# pygtk treeview contents update/refresh

Tags: python, sqlite, treeview

I finally managed to write a little app that reads from a sqlite database and show the results to a treeview. Another form (in another module) gives the ability to write new or update existing records. *After writing to the database it closes the window*

What I'm trying to do now is to update the "main" window (containing the treeview) to show the new dataset. I have managed so far to do this but a) the initial mainwindow stays there while a new instance of it opens on top of it showing the desired (new) dataset.

How would I make this work? Can someone give me suggestions/example?

Perhaps I need to say that the `__init__` function of my mainwindow module does everything upon running: creates the gui, reads from the database and show all. I suspect that this may be the problem but having tryed almost any combination of breaking it into pieces (functions), I had no success

*--EDIT--*

*OK I have many different functions* `__init__` *now creates the main gui while others read the data from the DB and place it on a treeview.*

*I tried to use a timer but also this option doesn't seem to be apropriate as* `gtk.TreeView` *doesn't have such a method.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I managed to figure this out, so I post this answer to my own question in case someone finds it helpful:

All I had to do was to `.clear` the list_store, rebuild it and use `set_model` to the TreeView.

The refresh function goes as below:

`liststore.clear()`

`create_model_checks() # re-create liststore`

`treeView.set_model(liststore)`